# maximum of a continuity function

Tags: functions, continuity

$$f(x)=\frac{(2x+\sin x)\arctan x}{x^2}$$

I need to explain if the function has a maximum over $(0,\infty)$.
If so, prove it without using derivatives.

Please give me a hint.

Comment: Local or global ?

Answer (score 4):

First notice that $2x+ \sin x \le 3x$, and $\arctan x < x$ for $x \in (0, \infty)$, so we have
$f(x) < 3$.

Now look at $\lim_{x \downarrow 0} f(x) $.

Comment: Very compactly done ! But doesn't it suffice to say that the function is bounded ?

Comment: Well, bounded and strictly monotonic would work, but in general, it could be bounded and attain a maximum (for example $x \mapsto \sin x$).

Comment: And ? It is just asked to show that there is a maximum.

Comment: Bounded doesn't imply that there is a maximum.

Comment: That's right, in case the maximum is at infinity. Are there other situations ?

Comment: The question asked if there was a $\max$, which there isn't. Here we have $\sup_{x \in (0,\infty)} f(x) =  \lim_{x \downarrow 0} f(x) = 3$, we have $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the plot of the function, you immediately see a single local maximum at $x=0$.

If Taylor is allowed, the behavior around the origin is

$$\frac{\left(2x+x-\frac{x^3}6+o(x^3)\right)\left(x-\frac{x^3}3+o(x^3)\right)}{x^2}=3-\frac{7x^2}6+o(x^2).$$

[image]

Comment: If derivatives are disallowed, Taylor should be as well. But then there is little left to handle the trigonometric functions.

Comment: Note that the function has no maximum on $(0,\infty)$. It has a $\sup$ but no $\max$.

Comment: Yep, that's right.

Comment: how can i show the function is monotonic  over(0,infinity)?